# printf signed integer and decimal point, issue with negative sign

Tags: c, printf

dsPIC33, XC16 compiler.

The dat1 is signed INT16, where it has value of 16434 and -16434 to be printed to 164.34 and -164.34.

```
printf("---: +/-180 from North   %d.%02d (deg)\n",(dat1/100),(dat1%100));
```

With dat1=164.34, I get

```
---: +/-180 from North -164.34 (deg)
```

With dat1=-164.34, I get

```
---: +/-180 from North -164.-34 (deg)
```

==> How to get rid of minus sign on '-.34'?

Comment: What about `abs(dat1)%100` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is almost correct, except you want to get rid off the sign in the second number. You can use this statement.

```
printf("---: +/-180 from North   %d.%02d (deg)\n", dat1/100, abs(dat1)%100);
```

*Edit:* <sub>Thanks to @chux.</sub>

The code above works in the desired range from -180.00 to 180.0 degrees. When you need a more general approach you should move the modulo operation before calling `abs()`.

Postponing the `abs()` avoids problems at INT_MIN since `abs(INT_MIN)` may give unexpected results. Then the code should be:

```
printf("---: +/-180 from North   %d.%02d (deg)\n", dat1 / 100, abs(dat1 % 100));
```

Comment: Minor: better to do `abs(dat1%100)` should `data1 == MIN_INT`.

Comment: @chux Where do you see the diff with your parentheses? In the range -18000 to 18000 you shouldn't have a problem. Fixed point arithmetic is always limited to the defined range.

Comment: If the range is limited to -18000 to 18000, certainly no issue.  As a general purpose answer though, using `abs(dat1)` where `dat1` is some signed integer is a problem in the singular case of 2's complement `abs(INT_MIN)` which is undefined behavior.  This is readily solved by `abs(dat1%100)`.